# Using Gson on a service

Tags: android, gson

For making my http requests, I'm using an Intent Service in conjunction with an ResultReceiver. The problem is that I need to pass to the service the type of the result that I want. Basically, a need to use Gson, in the service, in order to make this processing in the background. Something like this.

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<TYPE>(){}.getType();
receiver.send(200, gson.fromJson(json, collectionType));
```

But I can't find a way to pass the Type in the Intent. The code that start the service is this

```
protected void request(String url, Bundle parametros, int method, HttpInterceptor.Receiver callback){
    Type type = callback.getType();
    HttpInterceptor receiver = new HttpInterceptor(activity, new Handler());
    receiver.setReceiver(callback);
    receivers.add(receiver);
    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, RESTService.class);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    intent.putExtra(RESTService.EXTRA_AUTH, true);
    intent.putExtra(RESTService.EXTRA_PARAMS, parametros);
    intent.putExtra(RESTService.EXTRA_HTTP_VERB, method);
    intent.putExtra(RESTService.EXTRA_RESULT_RECEIVER, receiver);
    intent.putExtra(RESTService.EXTRA_TYPE, type); //not working
    activity.startService(intent);
}
```

I know that the class must be serializable, or parceable. But, even encapsulating type in a new Class, I can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, how about passing the fully qualified name of the object in intent instead (String format). And calling `Class.forName(fullyQualifiedName)` to have a Class to be passed on `gson.fromJson(json, resultOfClassForName)`

Comment: Class.forName() does not work with types like "java.util.Collection<java.lang.String>". Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial, hope this helps

http://benjii.me/2010/04/deserializing-json-in-android-using-gson/

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: My question  is not about how to use Gson.